# Обновление веб-сервиса, работающего под nginx

Tags: nginx, golang

Есть веб-сервис, написанный на Golang. Есть Nginx, который проксирует порт 80 на порт веб-сервиса.
При необходимости обновить бинарный файл веб-сервиса я должен остановить его работу, заменить файл на новый, запустить. Но во время этих манипуляций (даже если это всего несколько секунд), пользователи получают сообщения от Nginx "Service Temporarily Unavailable".

Вопрос: есть ли какие-либо способы обновлять бинарник без остановки работы сервиса?

Comment: Например, запускать новый бинарник одновременно со старым, перенаправлять nginx на него и только после этого выключать старый бинарник

Comment: @andreymal, да, об этом я думал. Но это постоянное жонглирование портами в коде и в nginx... думал, может есть более красивое решение

Comment: Ну, портов в коде быть вообще в принципе не должно (все порты должны быть в конфиге), а порты в nginx можно, например, вынести в отдельные файлы и переключаться простой заменой симлинка на нужный файл, можно даже автоматизировать скриптом. А вообще эта тема вроде как называется Blue-Green Deployment и неплохо гуглится (хотя взрослые дяди делают её с использованием контейнеров)

Comment: в nginx не нужно ничего переключать, посмотрите описание upstream, там как раз то, что нужно для вашей задачи

Comment: Присморись к этому костылю https://goteleport.com/blog/golang-ssh-bastion-graceful-restarts/ это позволит при рестарте обойтись вообще без downtime